How to use database.types.ts in Supabase edge functions?
I have a edge function in my supabase project called api. I am trying to call createClient with the generated Database types, but when running the function, supabase complains that it can't find it.
The database.types.ts file is at the root of my repo, and the edge functions are at /supabase/functions.
This is the file that seems to be causing the issue:
import { createClient } from "jsr:@supabase/supabase-js@2.45.6";
import { Database } from "../../../database.types.ts";

export function supabaseClient() {
  const url = Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL');
  const serviceRoleKey = Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY');
  return createClient<Database>(url!, serviceRoleKey!);
}

Running supabase functions serve api causes the following error:
worker boot error: failed to create the graph: Module not found "file:///programming/projects/my-working-repo/database.types.ts".
It seems like the database.types file is outside of the function, which is why it is not being found.
What would be the correct approach in this scenario?

I ended up moving the entire file into the supabase folder.
